# Wait at least 2 seconds if ajax completed before transition.next() with Vue.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

I need to display the spinner for at least 2 seconds if ajax has been completed
before transitioning.

I have the following but isnt working

```
route: {
    data(transition) {

        this.getDelayedData();
        transition.next();
       }
    },

methods:{   
   getSliders(){
            this.$http.get('/api/sliders/getsliders')
                   .then(sliders =>{this.sliders = sliders.data

              });
        },
   getPosts(){
            this.$http.get('/api/posts/getposts')
                    .then(posts =>{this.posts = posts.data.data

                    });
        },
   getDelayedData(){
       function timer() {
           var dfd = $.Deferred();
           setTimeout(function()
                    {
                    console.log("done");
                    }, 2000,dfd.resolve);
                    return dfd.promise();
                    }
           $.when( this.getPosts(), this.getSliders(),timer() )
                .done();
       }
    }
```

I tried to implement the code reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8336180/wait-to-return-from-a-javascript-function-until-condition-met) post 
But the $.when function isnt waiting until the setTimeout function is finished executing.

Comment: I am seeing few more things here... Your `function timer() {...}` is creating a new scope inside. So, technically your `this.getPosts()` and `this.getSliders()` should not even work inside the `timer` function. You may need to start using [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) everywhere as a habit.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have already accepted my other answer, but I think the code can be improved significantly, as explained below:

It is generally recommended not to mix `jQuery` with `Vue.js`, as both modify DOM:

- `Vue.js` has a very strong hold on the DOM, for its model-view bindings, using its **Reactivity System**
- `jQuery` may modify using `class` or `id` selectors, if you use it for some quick-fix solution somewhere.

You will end up spending a lot of time debugging frontend issues, which takes focus away from the business requirements. Also, `Vue.js` already requires modern browsers, so technically `jQuery` is not doing much for browser compatibility - its primary goal.

So if you are open to leaving `jQuery` behind, here is another method:

```js
getDelayedData() {
    // Create a new Promise and resolve after 2 seconds
    var myTimerPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            // callback function for timer, gets called after the time-delay
            // Your timer is done now. Print a line for debugging and resolve myTimerPromise
            console.log("2 seconds up, resolving myTimerPromise")
            resolve();
        }, 2000);  // This promise will be resolved in 2000 milli-seconds
    });

    // Start displaying ajax spinner before fetching data
    this.displaySpinner = true;

    // Fetch data now, within Promise.all()
    Promise.all([myTimerPromise, this.getPosts(), this.getSliders()]).then( () => {
        // Hide the spinner now. AJAX requests are complete, and it has taken at least 2 seconds.
        this.displaySpinner = false;
        console.log("Data fetched for sliders and posts");
    });
}
```

The above code also requires you to have `this.displaySpinner`, which activates or deactivates your ajax spinner. Or you may have some other way of doing it.

And you still need to `return this.$http.get(..)` from your `getPosts` and `getSliders` methods.

Note: I haven't tested the above code, you need to debug if required. It should work, based on my understanding of Promise.all() as given in this reference doc: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Once it starts working, you can simplify `myTimerPromise` as follows:

```js
getDelayedData() {
    // Create a new Promise and resolve after 2 seconds
    var myTimerPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(resolve, 2000);  // "resolve" is already a function, no need for another anonymous function here
    });
    // and do the other stuff here...
}
```

I would prefer this method, as it avoids `jQuery`. Then my `Vue.js` app can be as small as 30 KB gzipped, whereas if I bundle `jQuery` along, it can go well over 100 KB. It is just a personal choice :-)

Comment: Amazing Answer @Mani, you have taught me so many things. Of course I will leave jquery, just let me tell you for the Spinner Im using the $loadingRouteData var when the Data Route Hook is reached. I just need to Study your code and make the changes. then I will tell you how was it all. Once Again thanks!!

Comment: @FerchoCarcho Thanks for your feedback, and also thanks for making this the chosen answer. I guess this will help the community better than my other answer.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed answer. Timezones :D. you are true again, I have hard time to set things in one place, but your guide is very useful.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the problem is caused because your methods - `getSliders()` and `getPosts()` are not returning any Promises. So your `deferred` timer has no way of knowing what is going on in these get methods.

Your `this.$http.get(..)` from **Vue-resource** returns a promise. You can return it as follows:

```js
getSliders(){
    // Fetch sliders and "return" the promise object
    return this.$http.get('/api/sliders/getsliders')
        .then(sliders =>{
            // The data on vue is already being set here. So it will not wait for timeout.
            this.sliders = sliders.data
            // Instead you may try to set it on "this.sliders_temp" and then change later to "this.sliders"
        });
}, // and so on...
```

That follows the example given here: http://www.erichynds.com/blog/using-deferreds-in-jquery, which is linked in the other stackoverflow answer that you referred to in the question. They return `$.get(..)` in their functions.

But as indicated in my code sample above, even if you `return this.$http.get(...)`, it will still not work for you, because you are already setting `this.sliders` inside your success handler for `$http`. So your Vue template will update the UI immediately. You need to think through a better strategy for your app.

Comment: If you don't mind the data getting updated on page, and just want the spinner for 2 seconds, then simply `return this.$http.get(..)` will work, no other changes required.

Comment: Thank you @Mani  for the help :D

Comment: I believe it can be significantly improved. Check out my other answer, if it helps :-)